# Get 404 When Deploy WAR on Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, swagger, war

So I'm new to Tomcat, and I can't figure out why I keep getting 404 errors when I try to access my WAR file on my local Tomcat 7 server.  I've looked at several other posts on SO and elsewhere, but couldn't find anything.

Here's my service:

```
package io.swagger.api;

@Path("/postservice")
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.languages.JavaJerseyServerCodegen", date = "2017-04-15T00:29:22.981Z")
public class postserviceApi  {
 ....
}
```

Here's my Maven pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>MyAppWs</artifactId>
    <name>MyAppWs</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>APP-INF/lib</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>MyAppSchemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>MyAppUtils</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here's my web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
  xmlns:j2ee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyAppWsWs REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>
io.swagger.api
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.title</param-name>
            <param-value>Swagger Server</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
            <param-value>/MyAppApiWs</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Bootstrap</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>io.swagger.api.Bootstrap</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyAppWsWs REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>ApiOriginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>io.swagger.api.ApiOriginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ApiOriginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I'm accessing the following url:

localhost:8080/MyAppWs/postservice

I don't see any exceptions in the console.

Can someone help me identify what I need to change to access my service on Tomcat?

Comment: do you get any exception in tomcat server log. please share.

Comment: also provide the URL which you accessing.

Comment: Updated question